# DBeaver and SQLite connection through SSH

Tags: sqlite, ssh, dbeaver

With DBeaver, is it possible to use an SQLite database through an SSH connection?

If yes, how do I set up the connection?

Answer (score 1):

From a Dbeaver issue on [github](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6876), it's not possible.

> serge-rider commented on Nov 18, 2019
>
> You cannot use SSH with SQLite.
>   SQLite is embedded database, there is no such thing as SQLite server.
>   So SSH doesn't make any sense for SQLite.

I try it too, and don't find a working way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to mount the remote file system to your local file system over ssh?

```
sudo sshfs name@server:/path/to/folder /path/to/mount/point
```

I'm not sure how performant this would be, but theoretically it should hide from Dbeaver the fact that the database file is remotely located.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Install FTP on your Linux server](https://linuxopsys.com/topics/install-vsftpd-ftp-server-on-debian).
2. Test FTP connection using Windows file explorer by typing this in the navigation bar : `ftp://[ServerAdress]` ex: ftp://203.0.113.10
3. Create a new SQLite connection in Dbeaver. On path, click open and in file explorer type the same `ftp://[ServerAdress]`.